# What are the solutions for $2^x=x^2$?

Tags: exponential-function, quadratics

What are the solutions for $2^x=x^2$?

I noticed there were 2 roots: $2,4$.

Are there any other roots, and how do you calculate them?

Comment: there is a negative root. You can numerically approximate it. Just graph both curves carefully for $-1 < x < 5$ you will see that they cross three times.

Comment: Can you use Newton's Method?

Comment: Lambert W function can solve it for real and complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The answers include $2$,$4$ and the negative root is $-0.766665$.Since the bases are the same,setting the exponents equal to each other, you get this.If you want to see a better description of the answer, go to the page where it was first answered.